# Java Reflection - Method not found

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to find the method of a `PreparedStatement` (ps):

```
Method method = ps.getClass().getMethod("setLong", int.class, Class.forName("java.lang.Long"));
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(ps, fieldIndex, value);
```

but it isn't found. I have to use Class.forName("java.lang.Long") instead of Long.class.

For String it works:

```
Method method = ps.getClass().getMethod("setString", int.class, Class.forName("java.lang.String"));
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(ps, fieldIndex, value);
```

What am I doing wrong? Any idea? Is the namespace of Long wrong?

Comment: Why on earth would you use reflection, if you already have all values in hand? Simply call `ps.setLong(fieldIndex, value)`.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose maybe (one can always hope) this is one of those [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the legends talk about. And the `setAccessible` call indicates that those methods are not visible to the calling code. But they are, so maybe MrSct just thought they weren't :/

Comment: I have a string variable that tells me which type have to use like that: Method method = ps.getClass().getMethod("set"+ methodType, int.class, Class.forName(getFullNameClass(methodType)));

Comment: That still sounds like an xy problem. The actual type is determined by the statement or target column and whatever `set…` method you will use, the driver will attempt to convert the argument to the target type. It would be very strange, if you can’t just use [`setObject(int,Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-) or [`setObject(int,Object,type:int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-int-)…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second argument is [a `long`, not a `Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setLong-int-long-):

```
Method method = ps.getClass().getMethod("setLong", int.class, long.class);
```

Also, for a String, you don't need to call `Class.forName("java.lang.String")`: `String.class` would work as well.

But as commented, if you already have a `PreparedStatement` instace, you could simply call:

```
ps.setLong(fieldIndex, value);
```